# Why does `cd downloads` fail with "No such file or directory"?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, cd-command

Running Ubuntu 12.04, while in a terminal, I type `ls` and see list of folders, including the downloads folder. I then type `cd downloads`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I get:

```
bash: cd: downloads: No such file or directory
```

I tried each folder, on two computers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 18):

Linux file and directory names are case-sensitive. The default name of the downloads directory in Ubuntu is `Downloads` not `downloads`.

Comment: Probably a misunderstanding, rather than a blatant typo.

Comment: I just knew it would be something dumb! Many thanks

Comment: @RichDell You may want to [accept this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer).

Comment: The answer seems perfect but we can also let the system indifferent to CASE setting the inputrc file, see answer below

Answer (score 3):

To make Bash behave case-insensitively, edit your `~/.inputrc` (create it if it doesn't exist) and add

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

start a new shell (type `bash` or close the terminal and open a new one) or `source ~/.inputrc`, and then try

```
cd dowTab
```

and watch it complete to

```
cd Downloads/
```

Comment: While making tab-completion case-sensitive is a great thing, It doesn not answer the question why the `ls` command in this case didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe two things:

1. Spelling of the word i.e. you should type Downloads not downloads.
2. Downloads folder must be in Home directory

Answer (score 0):

It should `cd Downloads` with a capital D.