# Directory CMDs are not working

Tags: bash, scripts, directory, repository, database

I am unable to trigger commands in my command line
for example,

```
:~$ cd downloads 
Bash: cd: downloads: Bo such file or directory
```

Comment: See [Why does `cd downloads` fail with "No such file or directory"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152519/why-does-cd-downloads-fail-with-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in windows, paths are case-sensitive so doing `cd ~/downloads` does not work but `cd ~/Downloads` does.
There are some other differences like being able to use `!@#$%^&*+=-*`
Note `~` is the home directory